# Edit native component frontend (Activity view)

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps

is there any way to edit how a native component such as the list of tasks shown on accounts, opportunities etc behaves?

I would like to do things like "extend all notes by default".

I did not find any option to change the UI via loading and editing the component in the dev console?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no, you cannot reach into standard components and alter their behavior except in specific ways provided by Salesforce. For components, you'll find much of that configuration available to you upon selecting the component in the Lightning App Builder on your record page.

The Activity timeline offers very little customization. You will not be able to expand entries by default. Your modifications are largely limited to changing the fields displayed for each Activity line item; you can achieve this by editing the Task Compact Layout.

Beyond those allowed-for customizations, your next steps would be to install a third-party component from the AppExchange or build your own component.